# Bluetooth won't turn on, UBuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth

I was using my bluetooth earphones then they just disconnected and now I can't connect any device. The following images shows the output when I checked my bluetooth settings

[image]

I don't have a dongle. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Reboot. Any change?

Comment: It's still the same. I tried installing blueman but it still won't work

Comment: is it turned on or off,look at power settings.

Comment: It was turned off but would not allow me to turn it on. I am not sure what happened byt when I switch on my laptop 2 days late everything was functioning well, except the random crashing of LibreOffice packages. Thanks for responding.